# How can I batch resize images to a maximum of 2MB from the command line?

Tags: linux, image, imagemagick, command-line-interface

I looked at ImageMagick's `convert` and `mogrify` and am not sure how I should specify a maximum filesize when compressing. What do I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First google result: [https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ImageMagick's+max+file+size](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=ImageMagick%27s%20max%20file%20size)

Link: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php

```
jpeg:extent=value
//Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example -define jpeg:extent=400kb.
```